# Ubuntu auto mount exfat drive allow_other non root users access

Tags: permissions, mount, fstab, nfs, exfat

### Issue

- I have an exfat formatted drive.
- I'm able to unmount and mount it on an **ubuntu 20.04 desktop**.
- I can read files from it, however, I can only write files as root/sudo user. I've tried a lot of different settings with no success. Saw some comments about allow_other flag using fuseblk which I couldn't get fuseblk working.

I was able to use the ubuntu graphical **disks** application to mount and unmount. But still had issues with non root write permission.

Some other commands:

- `mkdir /home/drive1` mount point
- `sudo umount -f -l /home/drive1` force umount drive
- `code /etc/fstab` using visual studio code to open fstab and modify mount permissions
- `sudo mount -a` mount all drives in /etc/fstab, used to verify that mount settings aren't broken
- chown won't work for nfs and fat drives
- chmod 777 also won't work although there are some comments on +x executable working

### test user access

- `cd /home/drive1`
- `mkdir test` fails
- `sudo mkdir test` works
- `touch file.txt` fails
- `sudo touch file.txt` works

### mount attempts:

- `sudo mount /dev/sdb2 /home/drive1 -o rw,uid=yourusername,gid=yourusername`, sudo still required to write files

  - id yourusername
- `sudo mount -t vfat /dev/sdb2 /home/drive1 -o rw,umask=0000` runs but root still required
- `sudo mount -t exfat /dev/sdb2 /home/drive1 -o uid=1000,gid=1000` same issue
- `sudo mount -t exfat /dev/sdb2 /home/drive1 -o rw,allow_other,umask=0000` fails to mount with **allow_other**

### purpose

- trying to use external auto mounted exfat formatted drive as a volume for a docker container, read working, but write failing (even in docker container privileged mode)

### current solution

- since I wasn’t able to get any progress I decided to use nfs format instead which didn’t have this sudo issue. I could also try fedora instead and see if it still has the sudo exfat issue.

Comment: Read `man mount` paying attention to the `Mount options for fat` section. You can specify the `uid=`, `gid=`, `umask=` and other useful parameters.

Comment: yes it's 20.04, I don't know what you mean by snap **only**, I've had to remove snaps and apt install to fix some broken apps. @waltinator I've tried all those options with no success.

Comment: The mount options waltinator mentioned should be the way to go. After that recheck with `ls -la` if the files and folders and your mount point itself are still beeing owned by root. If that is the case do a chown on that mountpoint, files and folders again.

Comment: @AlexOnLinux I think you missed the point, chown doesn’t work on an exfat formatted drive. I ended up changing to nfs format instead.

Comment: @lastlink thx, i really missed that

Comment: I have the exact same issue, no matter what I use for options, it mounts it the exact same way.

/dev/sda2 on /mnt/1 type exfat (rw,relatime,fmask=0022,dmask=0022,iocharset=utf8,namecase=0,errors=remount-ro)

Answer (score 0):

After days of searching and try new things I make it work.

1. Unmount the drive
2. make new mount directory
3. install the exFat utilities from ubuntu with `sudo apt-get install exfat-fuse exfat-utils`
4. After that `sudo mount -a` and I have write access as user in my exFat directory

my fstab looks like

UUID=XXXX-XXXX /media/user/hdd exfat users,exec,rw,suid,dev,atime,diratime,uid=(1000,0),umask=000 0 0

Comment: does it stay mounted and working after a machine restart? I noticed that you mount using sudo `sudo mount -a`

Comment: yes it is stay mounted